# datepicker problem on passing value when submit for second time

Tags: php, datepicker

i have an issue on passing value thru datepicker. i have an appointment system which i use datepicker. i need to get the date and pass the value (on the same page) to my query and check it with my mysql database whether the date available or not. First pick date is ok and it send the right value, but when i try pick another date and submit it, it passing the first date that i choose. Is anyone know what is the problem?

```html
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['check']))
    {   
    $appdate = $_POST['appdate'];
  }

?>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" name="form">


<div class="form-group row">

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label for="jenis">Date Appointment</label>
      <input name="appdate" readonly="readonly" id= "appdate" type="text" class="form-control datepicker" data-format="dd-mm-yyyy" data-lang="en" data-RTL="false">
      <span class="help-block" id="error" style="color:red"></span> 
    </div>
                                            
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <label for="jenis"> <br></label>
      <input type="submit" name="check" id="check" value="Check" class="btn btn-3d btn-pink"/>
    </div>
                                                                                    
</div>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['check']))
    {   
    $appdate = $_POST['appdate'];
?>
<div>
  <p><?php echo $appdate; ?></p>
</div>
<?php 
  }
?>

</form>
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is the date properly added to the request? Have a look at your browser's network console for this

Comment: @NicoHaase i tried changing the passing value from $_POST to $_SESSION, also got the first date's value. Actually i just wanna passing the value to the same page so that i can get the date value and check into my mysql database before i proceed to the next page.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: @NicoHaase ok thank for your suggestion, already done editing and explain more details regarding on my question.